# Como capturar o clique num sub-item de uma Expandable List View

Tags: android

Então pesssoal, eu estou concluindo meu curso de t.i. no senai e estou desenvolvendo um TCC para o curso. Meu TCC consiste em um app de horários das linhas de ônibus da minha cidade. Para isso eu decidi criar uma expandable list view aprendendo por um vídeo no youtube, só que, não estou conseguindo fazer o “click” no sub-item da lista (clicou no bairro desejado, abriu as rotas e o usuário iria selecionar qual queria, pela sua escolha iria abrir uma activity com os respectivos horários da rota escolhida), por isso, precisava da ajuda de algum de vocês <3.

> Esta é a pasta java expandableListAdapter

```
package com.example.sesi2018.busu.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.sesi2018.busu.R;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by sesi2018 on 26/04/2018.
 */

public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private List<String> listDataHeader;
    private HashMap<String,List<String>> listHashMap;


    public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader, HashMap<String, List<String>> listHashMap) {
        this.context = context;
        this.listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
        this.listHashMap = listHashMap;
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return listDataHeader.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return listHashMap.get(listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return listHashMap.get(listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
      String headerTitle = (String)getGroup(groupPosition);
        if (convertView == null ) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group,null);
        }
        TextView lblListHeader = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
        lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
      final String childText = (String)getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
        if (convertView == null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item,null);
        }

        TextView txtListChild = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);
        txtListChild.setText(childText);
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

> Esta é a pasta da expandableListView

```
package com.example.sesi2018.busu.Activity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;

import com.example.sesi2018.busu.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class Turi extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ExpandableListView listView;
    private  ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
    private List<String> listDataHeader;
    private HashMap<String, List<String>> listHash;


    private ArrayAdapter<String> horariosadap;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_turi);

        listView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.lvExp);

        initData();
        listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this,listDataHeader,listHash);
        listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);




   getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Linhas - Turi");



        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                int posicaoClick = position;
                String conteudoClick = (String) listView.getItemAtPosition(posicaoClick);
                if(conteudoClick.equals("Isso é uma Expandable ListView")){

                    Intent bla2 = new Intent(Turi.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(bla2);

                }
            }
        });






    }

    private void initData() {
        listDataHeader = new ArrayList<>();
        listHash = new HashMap<>();

        listDataHeader.add("Alvorada");
        listDataHeader.add("Barreiro");
        listDataHeader.add("Bela Vista");
        listDataHeader.add("Catavento");

        List<String> lista1 = new ArrayList<>();
        lista1.add("Alvorada -> Centro");
        lista1.add("Alvorada -> Shopping");

        List<String> lista2 = new ArrayList<>();
        lista2.add("1");
        lista2.add("2");
        lista2.add("3");


        List<String> lista3 = new ArrayList<>();
        lista3.add("33");
        lista3.add("22");


        List<String> lista4 = new ArrayList<>();
        lista4.add("5");
        lista4.add("4");
        lista4.add("3");
        lista4.add("2");
        lista4.add("1");

        listHash.put(listDataHeader.get(0),lista1);
        listHash.put(listDataHeader.get(1),lista2);
        listHash.put(listDataHeader.get(2),lista3);
        listHash.put(listDataHeader.get(3),lista4);


    }




    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
        switch(item.getItemId()){
            case android.R.id.home:
                startActivity(new Intent(Turi.this,Horarios.class));
                finishAffinity();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }


}
```

[este foi o vídeo que assisti para fazer a expandablelist](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=akgvz8mFlkw)

Answer (score 0):

Em vez de `setOnItemClickListener()` tem de usar [setOnChildClickListener()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html#setOnChildClickListener(android.widget.ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener)).

Passe ao método um [ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener).

Na implementação do seu método [onChildClick()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener.html#onchildclick) use o  método `getChild()` do *adapter* passando o `groupPosition` e `childPosition` para saber qual o item clicado.